# Generating permutation of the string in c++

Tags: c++, string, c++11

This is the code which generates possible permutation using bit masking. I am having problem in understanding how is it executing after this condition when `i = 2 , bit = 4 , mask = 7`.

when `bit is 4` and `mask is 7` so condition `(bit & mask) == true` So it will continue .How i = 2 again ? and how mask becomes 1 when Mask will change when it will execute recurse(....)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void recurse(string s, int mask = 0,string out = "")
{ 
  int n = s.length();
  if (out.length() == n) cout << ' ' << out<<endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout<<"I:"<<i<<"=>";
    unsigned bit = 1 << i;
    cout<<bit<< " -> " <<mask<<endl;
    cout<<"cond:"<<(mask & bit)<<endl;
    if (mask & bit) continue;
    cout<<out+s[i]<<endl;
    recurse(s, mask | bit, out + s[i]);
  }
}

int main()
{
  string test = "red";
  recurse(test);
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
I:0=>1 -> 0
cond:0
r
I:0=>1 -> 1
cond:1
I:1=>2 -> 1
cond:0
re
I:0=>1 -> 3
cond:1
I:1=>2 -> 3
cond:2
I:2=>4 -> 3
cond:0
red
 red
I:0=>1 -> 7
cond:1
I:1=>2 -> 7
cond:2
I:2=>4 -> 7     <===== here when bit is 4 and mask is 7 so condition (bit & mask) == true
cond:4              So it will continue .How i = 2 again ? and how mask becomes 1 when Mask will change when it will execute recurse(....)
I:2=>4 -> 1
cond:0
rd
I:0=>1 -> 5
```

Comment: Are you aware of [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)? Especially the example part might be interesting for you.

Comment: @lubgr yes I know but I want to do it via bit masking method.

Comment: you are being confused by the debug prints which occur before `if (mask & bit) continue;`

Comment: @UmNyobe yes I aint able to see how output is produced at every step due to recursive function

Comment: Just to help debug recursive, I suggest adding a depth parameter to the function so that you can either print the number or print indenting spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a recursive algorithm, you need to stop recursing when you reached the termination condition (in your case it is `out.length() == n`). If this condition is triggered, you print found permutation, but what happens immediately after this? You continue to execute the function. In particular, you will iterate through the for loop which will print some output (meaningless at this point, because you reached the bottom of recursion). In fact, you got confused by the output messages printed after the recursion termination condition triggered. Add the return statement to your check for recursion termination:

```
if (out.length() == n) {
    cout << "OUT: " << out << endl;
    return;
}
```

This way you will avoid redundant recursive calls and won't see irrelevant output messages that can be confusing.

As for your question about why mask doesn't change - note that for values of `mask = 7` and `bit = 4` you get `maks | bit = 7| 4 = 7 = mask`. So in some cases, bitwise OR-ing mask and bit will not affect the mask.

Comment: `Since you are using recursive algorithm, you need to stop recursing somewhere.` technically it does stop.

Answer (score 0):

After the continue i = 3, and since n = 3 the loop stops.
So it goes up one recursion step and continues from the loop:

```
I:0=>1 -> 1
cond:1
I:1=>2 -> 1
cond:0
re
```

You can try printing a statement saying something like "finished loop" to see this.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Is it related to stack concept .Actually I am moving from top to bottom if recursion occurs then I go up and do the same thing . I guess you can't visualize it like this because it fails at that condition.

Comment: It is related to stack concept. The time of your problem is at recursion depth 3 and then it finishes two full methods and is therefore in recursion depth 1 and enters the statement again where i==2